# Is it possible to secure multiple seperately hosted api's behind a single APIResource

Tags: identityserver4

I'm working out how to model scopes for our system and conceptually had the idea that we could share scopes across our api's so users don't have to consent to a large number of scopes that are meaningless to them.

We are using IdentityServer 4 as our oauth implementation.

For example,

We have 2 services that provide timetable data that are on 2 separate api's hosted on two separate urls as they deal with different 3rd party systems.

The user is only interested on granting access to their Timetable data and so I was planning on a single scope (timetable.read) over 2 APIResource's which I've since found out is not allowed in IdentityServer see https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2304.

Is there anything wrong with conceptually modeling these as a single APIResouce within IdentityServer but using two discrete API's. I can't find anything that would prevent this in IdentityServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong really with what you are doing. If your multiple separately hosted api's are actually part of a single virtual api within your business problem domain, then the physical separation doesn't matter and as you have looked into already, there is nothing in the Identity Server 4 implementation that will prevent this.

Essentially, you just have to answer the question whether it makes sense in your context to have single api resource with multiple scopes and potentially share those scopes.